# What processes are started during linux boot and how to disable them?

Tags: boot, nfs

I installed nfs-commons on my Ubuntu 11.04 machine so that I can mount an NFS drive. However I late decided to remove NFS from my system so I did a sudo apt-get remove. Now, 1 out of 5 times my machine does not boot. It hangs. The boot messages say somewhere

> starting NFSv4 id <-> name mapper    [fail]

Also one of the message says

> init: statd pre-start process (505) terminated with status 2

Now I think both these messages have got something to do with my previous NFS installation. But I don't understand that when I have uninstalled it, why is my OS trying to start these services ? I don't have any entry for NFS in my fstab either.

So my question is this :

How do I find out what processes / services are going to start during boot and how do I disable them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are more familiar with the `chkconfig` utility, you may have a recap on which services are loaded/running at startup using:

```
chkconfig --list
```

of course you might have tu install the utility first but Ubuntu will tell you how to do it, just run it and see for yourself.

To enable/disable a service on the next boot just use the following syntax:

```
chkconfig --help
usage:   chkconfig [--list] [--type <type>] [name]
         chkconfig --add <name>
         chkconfig --del <name>
         chkconfig --override <name>
         chkconfig [--level <levels>] [--type <type>] <name><on|off|reset|resetpriorities>
```

In your case you should use:

```
sudo chkconfig <sericename> off
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu you can see a list of running services with:

```
service --status-all
```

and start or stop the service with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/service {stop,start}
```

Comment: I want the services to not start at all. What you are suggesting is that once started I can stop them.

Comment: Once you have identified what service(s) you don't want running, then stop them and then remove the relevant package(s).